In Chartjs, how can I set the scales.y.min value externally
I am using a linear chart and using it to visualise waveshapes that can be quite complex. The application requires the data y range to be pre-scaled based on variable external requirements, with typical limits being from (-10:0) through to (-500:0). By default, without an initial pre-scaled y axis, the chart dynamically rescales itself as the data arrives.
I need to pre-set the chartjs  variable into the chart structure prior to sending the data. Below I have called it the hypothetical .
scales: {
   y: {
      min: <NewNegativeValue>,
      max: 0,
      stepSize: 10,
      title:
         etc

I presume I can set this value in the same way I use javascript to set the other chart settings. What I don't understand is how to write it into the chart structure.
I spent several hours searching the web and although the concept of dynamic scaling is discussed, in all the cases I could find they dealt with examining the data and using the Math() function or something similar. In my case I know all about the data before calling the chart. I just need to know how to set the y  value via javascript prior to sending the data.
Ron

Just set the value using the chart instance, the value returned by the Chart constructor, const chart = new Chart(.....)- chart.options.scales.y.min = 22; .....; chart.update();. You don't need to have anything in place inside the initial configuration object.

Many thanks for that answer. I didn't understand the extent of the database I had access to.

To help any other newbies looking for this sometime in the future, here is how I implemented the answer. In the C++ after the minimum value had been discovered (my data is all negative):
// Now set the min scale for the chart y axis.
//
sprintf(text, "%d", (int32_t)MotorControl.GetAmplitude());
values["minValue"] = String(text);
jsonString = JSON.stringify(values);
events.send(jsonString.c_str(), "set_min_value", millis());

In the json script !!Windows.EventSource:
source.addEventListener('set_min_value', function(e) {
   var myObj = JSON.parse(e.data);
   setMinAxis(myObj.minValue);
}, false);

and in the chart script:
function setMinAxis(minValue) {
   myChart0.options.scales.y.min = Math.trunc(minValue);
{

My y axis are integers, and without the trunc function, on the chart the min value is displayed with a decimal point followed by dozen zeroes.
